# Extremely weird IE7/8 border/opacity compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, border

The weird problem is borders disappearing when Opacity is applied in IE/8/9, but NOT in 7!
I've basically got a menu with tabs on top of the screen.
I.e:

```
<table>  
 <tr>  
  <td class="tab">button 1...<*/td>  
  <td class="tab">button 2....<*/td>  
  .  
  .  
  .  
 </tr>  
 </table>  

 <style>  
 td  
 {  
    opacity: 0.45;  
    filter:alpha(opacity=45);  
    .  
    .  
    .  
 }  
 td.tab:hover  
 {  
    opacity: 1;  
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);  
 }
```

Sorry about the stars, I couldn't get the code block formatting working right.
Basically this is just supposed to unfade the buttons when the mouse is hovered over them, but the borders just disappear! This problem only occurs on IE8/9, but everything works fine on IE7,FF,Chrome,Safari.
I've trawled the internet looking for some weird IE8+ border/opacity issues, but there don't seem to be any.
Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: I just encountered the same issue, and I'm clueless.

Comment: do you have background-color set for your table cells, because it seems to happen only when background-color is set.

Comment: According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465346/table-cell-loses-border-when-css-gradient-filter-is-applied-in-ie8 table borders in IE8 seem to have probelms even with other filters

Comment: The border disappears when you mouseover the element?

Answer (score 3):

The `filter` style is for IE7 and lower only.

IE8 requires you to use `-ms-filter` (ie with a vendor prefix) instead. Plus the syntax is more complex in IE8. It looks like this:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
```

IE9 drops support for `filter` entirely, and replaces it with standard CSS3 `opacity`, which works the same as it does in all other browsrs.

Quirksmode.org has the full details: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of writing filter using the IE8 way. A wrong written filter in the worst case would not apply the opacity. Here the issue is that table cells border disappears.

Comment: filter: alpha(opacity= 100); // it varies from 0 to 100

Answer (score 0):

This is what I discovered so far, I don't think removing `background-color` of your table cells could be a solution for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      table {border-top:1px solid #cccccc; border-left:1px solid #cccccc;}
      table td {border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc; border-right:1px solid #cccccc; padding:3px;}      
      table tr.opaque td {
         -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
         filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1;}

      /* By adding background-color below, the table borders cells disappears
         in IE8. It's just the nth Microsoft's trigger tree!
         IE7 does not have this issue. */
      table tr.opaque td {background-color:#ffffff;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr><td><p>column 1</p></td><td><p>column 2</p></td><td><p>column 3</p></td></tr>
   <tr class="opaque"><td><p>column 1</p></td><td><p>column 2</p></td><td><p>column 3</p></td></tr>
   <tr><td><p>column 1</p></td><td><p>column 2</p></td><td><p>column 3</p></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the beautiful result when background-color is applied on **IE8**:

[image]

Comment: I eventually had to resort to moving the background color from the td to a div within the td(the div had to be slightly larger than the td to make it appear seamless) , while keeping the opacity and border on the td and having background:none on the td;

Comment: @Metatron: interesting new IE8 hack. I'm gonna try your solution and let you know. Thanks for sharing this idea.