# IE8 table row gradient filter doesn't show in table cell

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, border, gradient

Short version: I've set a gradient filter to a `<tr>` tag, but in IE8 the child `<td>` and `<th>` tags ignore it completely, no matter what their background properties are.

Here's an example of what I'm looking at: http://jsfiddle.net/FlashbackJon/NqkGv/3/

Normally, I would just apply it to the table cell tags, but as I am now well-aware (from [countless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995189/extremely-weird-ie7-8-border-opacity-compatibility-issue) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465346/table-cell-loses-border-when-css-gradient-filter-is-applied-in-ie8)), filters are rendered on top of element background contents, including the borders, and I need the table borders in place and collapsed.  I'm using the HTML5 doctype and the company standard is IE8 for the bulk of our end users.

I'm trying to keep it image-free and would desperately like to avoid unnecessary HTML.  If there's simply no way to make the row gradient visible, I may have to resort to that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make the row gradient visible, it just doesn't apply to tr tags.

Comment: That is what I assumed was happening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx

> Specific elements that cannot have filters and transitions applied to them include:
>
> - The embed and applet elements
> - The select and option form elements
> - The **tr**, tHead, tBody, and tFoot table elements

Answer (score 0):

Is the gradient somehow super crucial to your layout? I would recommend just dropping it altogether for IE8 - odds are the experience won't be broken, just different.

Filters in IE have a high performance cost - so they should be used when you really, really need it. I would argue the background color to a table row is probably not one of those times. Your site will perform faster, and your users will be just as happy.

Comment: Crucial to the layout?  No, just building to the designers' specs.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a horizontal gradient, you can apply it to the TDs instead of the TRs. It'll work, and look the same. TR's aren't treated as "real" elements in older IE, they're like an abstract container for TDs. The TDs pick up style fine though.

Comment: You didn't really understand his issue.  His issue is that he wants to have borders on his tables, and if he uses the filter on the TD's it overwrites the borders, so your suggestion is already mentioned in his question and dismissed as not suitable.