# Table Header borders disappearing in IE8 with gradient background

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, border, css-tables

My tables are causing problems in IE8.  I cannot get the dividing borders in the table header to appear above the gradient (except for in one spot, which you can see in the image below).  The borders appear fine in every other browser and even in IE8 Compatibility Mode.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  [Here](http://inspecttech.com/mockup/gridview.html) is a test site for everyone to see the applied code.

[image: Comparison of table header borders in IE8 and IE8 Compatibility Mode]

Here is the table header's CSS, but you can view the entire CSS file [here](http://inspecttech.com/mockup/inspecttech_styles.css):

```
.gridview th {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #005383 0%, #90d9ff 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #005383 0%, #90d9ff 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #005383 0%, #90d9ff 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #005383 0%, #90d9ff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #005383 0%, #90d9ff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#90d9ff, endColorstr=#005383);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#90d9ff, endColorstr=#005383)";
    background-color: #005383;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #005580;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: As in @DextrousDave 's answer this is in fact a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465346/table-cell-loses-border-when-css-gradient-filter-is-applied-in-ie8 - where `position: relative` on your `th` will fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table cell loses border when css gradient filter is applied in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465346/table-cell-loses-border-when-css-gradient-filter-is-applied-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, but I'm not very happy with it since it isn't valid HTML anymore...but this seems to fix the problem in older versions of IE:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

I showed this to my boss, he did not approve, so I am still looking for a solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving your problem but but could not. I see that this occurs in both IE8 and IE9 doc and browser mode. Not in IE 7 however. But when using only

```
 background-image: url(data:image/.......);
```

the borders work in IE9...that only leaves IE 8 to solve. You can use IE7 and IE9 specific conditional commentsa to use above code(for IE9) and the

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft
```

for IE7.
With regard to the problem in IE8, here is a similar post:

[Table cell loses border when css gradient filter is applied in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465346/table-cell-loses-border-when-css-gradient-filter-is-applied-in-ie8)

Comment: Thank you for that link...I created a fix (although I'm not very happy with it) which I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12062157/1538918).  I wouldn't have thought of this without your link so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my css was a solution for me:

```
table {
   border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions I've searched on worked. For IE8, the background color only worked for the body table rows. Whenever I used a background color for the header row or header column, the borders would disappear.

What worked for me was defining a background color for the table itself. No background color for header. Each body table row would need to have a background color defined to overwrite the color defined on the table (if needed).